# Extension Methods in VB 2008 assembly cannot be used in a C# project?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, extension-methods

I wrote some string extension methods in a VB assembly and am unit testing them from a C# project. However, C# acts like it cannot see the the extension methods, when other VB projects reference the VB assembly they have no problem. Both the VB assemebly and the C# test project are targeting .Net 3.5.

Is there a way around this?

---

**VB.Net extension methods:**

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports System.Linq

Namespace ExtensionMethods
    Module StringExtensions

        <Extension()> _
        Public Function Remove( _
                            ByVal input As String, _
                            ByVal subStrings As String()) As String
            ...
        End Function

        <Extension()> _
        Public Function Substrings( _
                            ByVal input As String, _
                            ByVal regexPattern As String, _
                            ByVal regexOptions As RegexOptions) As IEnumerable(Of String)
            ...
        End Function

        <Extension()> _
        Public Function Substrings( _
                            ByVal input As String, _
                            ByVal regexPattern As String) As IEnumerable(Of String)
            ...
        End Function
    End Module
End Namespace
```

**VB.Net usage:**

```
Imports SomeNamespace.ExtensionMethods
...
someString = someString.Remove(subStringsToRemove)
```

**C# usage (doesn't work):**

```
using SomeNamespace.ExtensionMethods;               //No error, but ExtensionMethods is not in the intellisense
...
someString = someString.Remove(subStringsToRemove);  //error, can't find matching overlaod
```

Comment: Tried to make the module 'Public'?

Comment: Might want to check if you can invoke explicitly (StringExtensions.Remove(someString, subStringsToRemove);) to see if it can even find the class...

Comment: @Kamarey, that worked! Feel free to make your comment an answer and I'll accept it. Stupid mistake on my part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tried to make the module 'Public'?

Update:

Can't explain why it worked with other VB assemblies. Think that C# has its own vision of class access modifiers or something.

Comment: I went back and looked at the code, and while I intended to use the extensions elsewhere, I have not done so yet. It's only been used in it's container assembly. Default access modifier's for classes/modules in VB are internal, just like C# classes. I suppose this could also happen if the assembly had `InternalsVisibleTo` set to allow other assemblies to see a module like this, but that isn't the case here. Thanks for the second pair of eyes to catch my small typo.